# 2 block buttons next to each other not working in bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I recently updated to bootstrap 5.

I have these block buttons:

[image]

When I followed the bootstrap instructions here
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons
my buttons are always shown on top of each other:

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        System-Test
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <p>Hier kann das Verhalten der Anwendung getestet werden, insbesondere das Verhalten im Fehlerfall.</p>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Admin/Control?command=TestException">Ausnahme testen</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Admin/Control?command=TestMessage">System-Nachricht testen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to display the buttons like block buttons and next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the button's container (the most nested `div`) to flex and apply 50% width for buttons:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between gap-4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary w-50" href="/Admin/Controlcommand=TestException">Ausnahme testen</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary w-50" href="/Admin/Control?command=TestMessage">System-Nachricht testen</a>
</div>
```